# Error creating Email for addon domain Cpanel

Tags: error-handling, cpanel

hey guys I need your godly advice I have set up my Webhosting from a NON-cpanel server to a cpanel server and am trying to create an email account for one of my addon domains EG main domain is EG main.com addon new_main.com so I try and create for my addon in cpanel like email@new_main.com and I am met with this error. please note I used to years ago be on cpanel so it may have brought files from the old install over to this new install which is possibly causing the issue but I'm lost trying to figure out what's wrong

fingers crossed you guys can see the error I have been looking at this for a day now and I still can't seem to figure out, I have looked for the files mentioned and some are there 1 of them isn't cant remember which and I don't know how to remedy the situation thanks in advance

The error looks like this

````
Error: The operation “POST” “/cpsess8393558881/execute/Email/add_pop” failed with a “The system could not create the calendar “Calendar” for “contact@combatprosports.co.uk”: Cpanel::Exception::Database::Error/(XID rg8xc9) The system received an error from “SQLite”: SQLITE_READONLY (attempt to write a readonly database) at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/DBI.pm line 200. Cpanel::DBI::_create_exception(Cpanel::DBI::db=HASH(0x2b39d20), "DBD::SQLite::db do failed: attempt to write a readonly database", undef) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/DBI.pm line 188 Cpanel::DBI::_error_handler("DBD::SQLite::db do failed: attempt to write a readonly database", Cpanel::DBI::db=HASH(0x2b39d20), undef) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/DAV/Backend/DB/Horde.pm line 79 eval {...} called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/DAV/Backend/DB/Horde.pm line 79 Cpanel::DAV::Backend::DB::Horde::do(Cpanel::DBI::db=HASH(0x2b39d20), " INSERT INTO kronolith_shares\x{a} (share_name, share_owner"..., "14a47cf5-a4b7-b2f9-5d71-7e972f886226", "contact\@combatprosports.co.uk", "Calendar", "This is your personal calendar.", "#641f76") called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/DAV/Backend/HordeCalendar.pm line 82 Cpanel::DAV::Backend::HordeCalendar::create_calendar(Cpanel::DAV::Principal=HASH(0x281d938), "Calendar", "This is your personal calendar.") called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/DAV/Calendars.pm line 59 Cpanel::DAV::Calendars::create_calendar(Cpanel::DAV::Principal=HASH(0x281d938), "Calendar", "This is your personal calendar.") called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/DAV/Defaults.pm line 55 Cpanel::DAV::Defaults::create_calendar(Cpanel::DAV::Principal=HASH(0x281d938)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/DAV/Defaults.pm line 142 Cpanel::DAV::Defaults::create_calendars_and_address_books("contact\@combatprosports.co.uk") called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/API/Email.pm line 1478 Cpanel::API::Email::add_pop(Cpanel::Args=HASH(0x2451f80), Cpanel::Result=HASH(0x244a6d8)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/API.pm line 366 eval {...} called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/API.pm line 368 Cpanel::API::_run_module_function(Cpanel::Args=HASH(0x2451f80), Cpanel::Result=HASH(0x244a6d8), "Email", "add_pop") called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/API.pm line 243 Cpanel::API::execute("Email", "add_pop", HASH(0x244a588)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/API.pm line 651 Cpanel::API::run_api_mode(HASH(0x244a588)) called at uapi.pl line 307 main::script() called at uapi.pl line 139 ” error.```
````

Answer (score 0):

The error message contains the following:

```
SQLITE_READONLY (attempt to write a readonly database)
```

This is not normal and suggests that there is a problem with the server's disks. You should reach out to your hosting provider, or if you are the owner of the server, a systems administrator that has the skills, training, and experience required to check the status of the disks, and/or determine why the SQLITE database is readonly.

Comment: i run it from a VPS myself and govern t the system myself kind of thing, the server used to be hosted on a shared hosting platform and has since moved to a hosted vps so mam guessing the perms of the error you pointed to is probably still set to the old servers perms and that is causing it (that's a complete guess obviously )

Comment: In my personal experience, the most common cause for one of the SQLITE databases that cPanel uses to go readonly  is filesystem corruption. You should review the output of `systemctl -b` , `less /var/log/messages`, `dmesg | less` and look for evidence of filesystem related errors.